# I have 22,1 GB of movie data totally that I want to put on several DVDs

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 22,1 GB of movie data totally that I want to put on several DVDs.

I want ffmpeg to create one long 22.1 GB mp4 file from a lot of small files to then split them into as many 4.7 GB mp4-files as necessary(should fit on 5 DVDs), so the order is preserved.

Which command do I need?

I started with `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy -fs 5046586573 output1.mp4` with `mylist.txt` containing

```
# this is a comment
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

Then looking at the duration, to then continue with `ffmpeg -ss duration -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy -fs 5046586573 output2.mp4`

Which command does that at once?

Comment: You could do it that way, but I recommend [mp4box](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/) if you need to segment the input by bytesize. Look up the `-splits` option.

Comment: @Mulvya Is it true that there are no binaries for mp4box and you have to compile them using vs for windows?

Comment: No. Get them from https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/

Comment: @Mulvya What is the exact command for my purpose with mp4box?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mp4box to join the files as well, then use

```
mp4box -cat 1.mp4 -cat 2.mp4 -cat 3.mp4 -splits 4928307 newprefix.mp4
```

This gets you

```
newprefix_001.mp4
newprefix_002.mp4
...
```

mp4box can only split at keyframes, so the segments may overshoot the split size if the GOP doesn't end at the split size (very likely). So, the safe thing to do is to specify a size which is one GOP less than the intended limit. So take the video stream bitrate and multiply by 10. Divide by 8192 to convert to kilobytes and subtract that from the actual segment size limit.

Comment: My goal is to 1. concatenate the files to then split this huge video file by size in one step. All you do is split a huge file, which does not exist.